# how can i get Observable value in return string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, single-page-application

i'm new to here please help me how can i get return value in Component from Service

**Service.ts**

```
name:string = 'John';
 GetSecureTokene(_hero:Users){    
    debugger;
    if(_hero.Email=='abc' && _hero.PassWord==123){
      return this.name;     
    }
```

**Component.ts**

```
submitForm(vale:any){
    debugger;
   this._AuthServiceService.GetSecureTokene(vale).subscribe----
//Here how can i Get name from service 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the code from your service to this

```
import { of, Observable } from "rxjs";

GetSecureTokene(_hero:Users): Observable<string> {    
 if(_hero.Email=='abc' && _hero.PassWord==123){
    return of(this.name);     
 }
}
```

And in your component

```
submitForm(vale:any) {
   this._AuthServiceService.GetSecureTokene(vale).subscribe(res => {
     console.log(res);
   })
}
```

Comment: Typo in "subscxribe" :-)